# How can I merge two Vertices into one using Apache Gremlin Query Language (Version 3.5.2)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Take for example this graph model:

```
g.addV("TopVertex").property('id', 4713).property('testProperty1','testProperty1').as('vertex1')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C1').as('C1')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C2').as('C2')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C3').as('C3')
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex1').to('C1').property('ordinal',1)
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex1').to('C2').property('ordinal',2)
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex1').to('C3').property('ordinal',3)

.addV("TopVertex").property('id', 4713).property('testProperty2','testProperty2').as('vertex2')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C4').as('C4')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C5').as('C5')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C6').as('C6')
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex2').to('C4').property('ordinal',4)
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex2').to('C5').property('ordinal',5)
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex2').to('C6').property('ordinal',6)
```

Now I want to merge 'vertex1' and 'vertex2' to one 'mergedVertex', so that 'mergedVertex' has all six SubVertex. How do I achieve that using Gremlin Query Language and a AWS Neptune databse?

Since i am not that familiar with Gremlin I basically trialed and error to the solution

Comment: When you say "merge", do you want do delete the current edges and create new ones from all the SubVertex nodes to the new "mergedVertex" ? You could do this as a single Gremlin query but it might get a little complex. You could also break the task up into two queries and a bit of application logic which would be by far the simplest approach.

Comment: So i was basically aiming for the first approach. But I also want to have the old properties in the new edges. If it possible I would do it in one query. If there is no other way around I can also add Java logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is now my currently working solution, any tips for improvement?

Edit: To further explain my solution. My aim was to create a new merged Vertex and copy the edges from the old two vertices to the new merged one.

```
g.addV("MergedVertex").property('id', 4713).as('mergedVertex'). //add new vertex to traversal
V().hasLabel("TopVertex").has('id', 4713).as('oldVertices'). //get all vertices with the label "TopVertex" and the provided id
       outE().as('oldEdges'). //get all outgoing edges
       inV().as('inVertices'). // get all in vertices of these
       select('mergedVertex'). 
       addE('splitsInto').to('inVertices').as('newEdges'). //add new edges to the mergedVertex
       sideEffect(select('oldEdges').properties(). //the sideEffect section copies the properties of the old edges and pastes them into the newEdges
                  unfold().as('props').
                  select('newEdges').
                  property(select('props').key(), select('props').value())).
       select('oldVertices').drop() //with the last step we drop the old vertices
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Also, to @scully’s point, you should avoid asking follow-up questions in your answers. Generally, members of the community don’t need a prompt to offer tips for improvement.